# Point in Polygon Hadoop implementation

Tags: hadoop, geometry, geospatial, computational-geometry, apache-pig

I have a big log file with some (Lat, Long) coordinates, and a database with a collection of polygons. The polygons dataset fits in memory now, but not maybe in the future.

I want to join these two datasets in order to know, for every log coordinate, which polygons is it contained in.

Do you know what is a good approach to this problem using Hadoop (or Pig if it helps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of search results that arrive here, one or more of the following would be useful:

[GIS Tools for Hadoop](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop)

[SpatialHadoop](http://spatialhadoop.cs.umn.edu/)

[HadoopGIS](http://confluence.cci.emory.edu:8090/display/HadoopGIS/Home)

(Disclosure: I am one of the developers of GIS Tools for Hadoop, and employed by Esri.)

Answer (score 0):

At a first sight I would propose doing like this:

Having a map which uses MultipleInputs (the database polygons and a split from the log file).
For each point in the log file split it checks whether the point belongs to a polygon and outputs the pair (point,polygon) if it does.

The reducer aggregates this information and outputs : (point, set of polygons it belongs to).

This solutions does not  assume that the hole set of polygons fits in main memory.

If you're sure it does, I think that querying the database before starting the job and placing the result of the query as a file in the DistributedCache would be more efficient.